# Setting up ArcMap to debug scripts in PyCharm?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, pycharm, debugging

I'm wondering whether anyone succeeded at setting up ArcMap to debug python scripts in PyCharm. I've tried several times to configure both, but failed.

Comment: This question is not about importing arcpy in PyCharm but debugging scripts as they are running in `ArcMap.exe`. This question _is not_ a duplicate.

Comment: In the ArcMap Geoprocessing Options, have you set the Debugger texbox to the full path of Pycharm.exe?

Comment: I'm able to debug a python script, in PyCharm, that was run from an ArcMap toolbox script. From Catalog or ArcMap, right-click the script, select debug. After PyCharm opens, select debug to start a debug session.

Comment: I do this for IDLE and nothing happens. I have to leave it blank and use note pad :(

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up [remote debugging](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2010/12/python-remote-debug-with-pycharm/). I know the Wing IDE equivalent works in ArcMap, I assume if you set it up right PyCharm would as well.

Answer (score 1):

Under Geoprocessing Options enter the path to your Pycharm program in the editor and debugger input boxes.

e.g.
`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\bin\pycharm.exe`